# PySpark ChiSqSelector p-values and test statistics

Tags: python, pyspark, chi-squared

I am using PySpark's [`pyspark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelector`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelector) to perform feature selection. `apps` is a column containing sparse matrices which correspond to whether a particular `name` (machine) has installed a particular application. All in all, there are 21,615 possible applications someone could have installed.

After fitting and transforming new data using the `ChiSqSelector` object, I am confused as to what `selected_apps` now represents. The documentation is less than helpful, here. I have a few questions:

1) How can I obtain the chi-square test statistics and p-values associated with each of the 21,615 input applications? This doesn't seem immediately accessible through looking at `dir(selector)`.

2) Why are different applications shown in `selected_apps`? My hunch is that the machine in the second row below doesn't have apps 0, 1, 2, etc., so what is shown in `selected_apps` for that row are the top 50 applications it *does* have based off their p-values. This API seems a lot different from scikit-learns `SelectKBest(chi2)` effort, where just the top *k* most relevant features are returned, irrespective of whether a particular machine has a "1" for that feature.

3) How can I override the default `numTopFeatures=50` setting? This is primarily related to question 1) and utiliizing just the p-values for feature selection. There doesn't seem to be a `numTopFeatures=-1`-type option for basically "forgetting" about this parameter.

```
>>> selector = ChiSqSelector(
...     featuresCol='apps',
...     outputCol='selected_apps',
...     labelCol='multiple_event',
...     fpr=0.05
... )
>>> result = selector.fit(df).transform(df)                                                                
>>> print(result.show())
+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|           name|total_event|multiple_event|                apps|       selected_apps|
+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|000000000000021|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000022|          0|             0|(21615,[3,6,7,8,9...|(50,[3,6,7,8,9,11...|
|000000000000023|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000024|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000025|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000026|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000027|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000028|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000029|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000030|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000031|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,4...|(50,[0,1,2,3,4,6,...|
|000000000000032|          0|             0|(21615,[6,7,8,9,1...|(50,[6,7,8,9,13,1...|
|000000000000033|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,4...|(50,[0,1,2,3,4,6,...|
|000000000000034|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000035|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000036|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000037|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000038|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000039|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,6...|(50,[0,1,2,3,6,7,...|
|000000000000040|          0|             0|(21615,[0,1,2,3,4...|(50,[0,1,2,3,4,6,...|
+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Solution below:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

# Convert everything to a LabeledPoint object, the main consumption
# data structure for most of mllib
to_labeled_point = lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[0], Vectors.dense(x[1].toArray()))

obs = (
    df
    .select('multiple_event', 'apps')
    .rdd
    .map(to_labeled_point)
)

# The contingency table is constructed from an RDD of LabeledPoint and used to conduct
# the independence test. Returns an array containing the ChiSquaredTestResult for every feature
# against the label.
feature_test_results = Statistics.chiSqTest(obs)

data = []

for idx, result in enumerate(feature_test_results):
    row = {
        'feature_index': idx,
        'p_value': result.pValue,
        'statistic': result.statistic,
        'degrees_of_freedom': result.degreesOfFreedom
    }
    data.append(row)
```